# Create a Table to store shared attributes between tables, how to deal with Composite Keys?

Tags: sql, database, composite-primary-key

I'm looking for a Database solution for dealing with scenario like this:

A lot tables: TableA, TableB, TableC ... share some attributes(fields), I want to store these shared attributes in a table, let's call it Shared Table.
like this:

```
TableA:
| KeyA  | Shared Attr.1  | ... | Other Attr.   |
| A_1   | A_SValueA1     | ... | A_OValueA1    |

TableB:
| KeyB  | Shared Attr.1  | ... | Other Attr.   |
| B_1   | B_SValueA1     | ... | B_OValueA1    |

Shared Table:
| KeyShare  | EntityType | Shared Attr.1   | ... |
| A_1       | A          | A_SValueA1      | ... |
| B_1       | B          | B_SValueA1      | ... |
```

Of course I'll create one table to store specific attributes for each table.

But I need to solve this problem, Table C, which I also want to store its shared attributes in SharedTable, has composite keys, like this:

```
TableC:
| KeyC1 | KeyC2  | Shared Attr.1  | ... | Other Attr.   |
| C1_1  | C1_2   | C_SValueA1     | ... | C_OValueA1    |
```

So I can't deal with it just like TableA and TableB. 
Is there any good design to deal with Composite Keys in table like C?
I'm sure this is not some new questions, a lot people may have faced and solved it, but I searched a lot and failed to find existing questions.

---

In fact, this scenario is designed as an alternative of E-A-V antipattern, because TableA/B/C are of the same class, so they have shared attributes, and they act as subclass, so they have special attributes.

In class level, they are same things, they can be compared, sorted, calculated, so they are designed to be placed in one table.

Comment: I am sorry. I tried really hard and I can not understand what you are trying to achieve. I know how to create a SharedTable out of TableA and TableB. But what you want to do with TableC is a mystery to me.

Comment: @Boris Shchegolev I want to store shared attributes of TableC in SharedTable, just like what I do with TableA and TableB. But TableC has more than one primary key, when SharedTable has only one.

Comment: Seems like a variant of the One True Lookup Table anti-pattern.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In fact, this is designed as an alternative of E-A-V antipattern, because TableA/B/C are of the same class, so they have shared attributes, and they act as subclass, so they have special attributes. In class level, they are same things.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want this (and I concur with the other answer that this is a bad[tm] idea) - turn the solution upside-down:

Don't store the key to the particular entity in the shared table, store a reference to a new "Shared Entity" in your particular table.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  my_special_attr VARCHAR,
  shared_attr_set INT REFERENCES Shared(attr_set_id)
);
CREATE TABLE TableC (
  id1 INT,
  id2 VARCHAR(2),
  my_special_attr VARCHAR,
  shared_attr_set INT REFERENCES Shared(attr_set_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2)
);
CREATE TABLE Shared (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  attr_set_id INT,
  shared_attr_1 INT,
  shared_attr_2 VARCHAR
);
```

Of course this means you'll have to cleanup after yourself if you remove instances of particular classes - you'll either need to scan `Shared` for "orphaned" sets or delete them together with the instance.

Let me end with a word of warning: I've been there. I messed up. This is a recipe for a *lot* of headaches. Consider making `Shared` a full entity and use [composition over inheritance](https://www.thoughtworks.com/de/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose).

Answer (score 1):

understanding it's by-design to be an alternative of E-A-V anti pattern, if you really want to make it work, perhaps you can use single primary key for your table C: Adding a new auto-increment column that set as primary key and leave your composite key columns as is, but adding a unique-constraint on them.

this would resolve the issue on the shared table. though query might be a headache later...

another approach I've seen before is that using a parent table that holds the keys and common columns, while children extend the table to have specific columns. sample:

```
TableParent:
| Key  | Type | Shared Attr.1  | Shared Attr.2  |... | Other common Attr. |
| P_1  | A    | Value A1       | Value A2       |... |                    |
| P_2  | B    | Value B1       | Value B2       |... |                    |
| P_3  | C    | Value C1       | Value C2       |... |                    |
Key column is auto-incremental primary key column   

TableChildA:
| Key  | Col1 | Col2  | ... |
| P_1  | Val 1| Val 2 | ... |
The Key column is not auto-incremental, but foreign-keyed back to TableParent Key column

TableChildB:
| Key  | Col3 | Col4  | ... |
| P_2  | Val 3| Val 4 | ... |
The Key column is not auto-incremental, but foreign-keyed back to TableParent Key column

TableChildC:
| Key  | Composite Key 1 | Composite Key 2 |Col5 | Col6  | ... |
| P_3  | key 1           | Key 2           |Val 5| Val 6 | ... |
The Key column is not auto-incremental, but foreign-keyed back to TableParent Key column
Also there is a unique constraint on Composite Key 1 + Composite Key 2
```

literally in your code, you can have parent class of TableParent while having separate children class for TableA/B/C...

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever here. This sounds really much like OTLT.

Aggregating data from TableA and TableB can be achieved through inheritance:

```
CREATE TableA INHERITS SharedTabele;
CREATE TableB INHERITS SharedTabele;
```

or use of a view:

```
CREATE VIEW SharedTable AS
SELECT * FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TableB
```

But when you explained you are trying to push a radically different TableC into the same shared table I realized something is terribly wrong. This is hard to do exactly because it does not make much sense.

Please, consider changing your approach. OTLT will not solve anything and it will definitely make things more complicated.

Comment: Hi Boris, thanks a lot for your reply, I just added comment to Damien_The_Unbeliever  that if I've made it correct, this is designed as an alternative of E-A-V antipattern.